# javascript Regex split UpperCase from lowerCase

Tags: javascript, regex, string, uppercase, lowercase

I got a string like:

```
var str = new Array( 
"Inverted HFFSfor Primary Wrap Or Secondary Multi Wrap",
"HFFSwith PDSPbackgroud Feederlense & Product Alignerigit",
"HFFSwith Cooler JKLHbetween Feeder & Product Aligner")
```

How to separate i.e.

1) **HFFSfor** to become **HFFS for**

2) **HFFSwith** to become **HFFS with**

3) **PDSPbackgroud** to become **PDSP backgroud**

4) **JKLHbetween** to become **JKLH between**

and so forth...

My first instinc was something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i<_str.length; i++){ 
if( (/*The needed Regex*/).test(_str[i]) ){


     }  
}
```

No Success.... Can't seem to think further!!

Please help, Thanks

Comment: You don't have a `+` after your uppercase range?

Comment: Tested with .test() still no success...  Kindly remove your DownVote. Thanks

Comment: `.replace` method doesn't accept regular expressions as its replacement argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` doesn't accept a rgex, you can use a `.replace` like this.

You can use:

```
var repl = str.replace(/\B([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[a-z]))/g, '$1 ');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rhOLG2/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\B`: Asserts positions where word boundary doesn't
- `(`: Start capturing group #1

  - `[a-z](?=[A-Z])`: Match lowercase letter if there is a uppercase letter ahead
  - `|`: OR
  - `[A-Z](?=[a-z])`: Match uppercase letter if there is a lowercase letter ahead
- `)`: End closing group #1

Comment: This Worked perfectly (Accepted)... Please UpVote the Question cause it is a Valid Question for SO. Thank

Answer (score 1):

You might try this, capture words that are made of more than one upper case letters (as one group) and lower case letters (as another group) and then add a space between the two groups:

```js
var str = new Array( 
"Inverted HFFSfor Primary Wrap Or Secondary Multi Wrap",
"HFFSwith PDSPbackgroud Feederlense & Product Alignerigit",
"HFFSwith Cooler JKLHbetween Feeder & Product Aligner")

console.log(
  str.map(s => s.replace(/([A-Z]{2,})([a-z]+)/g, "$1 $2"))
)
```